# receive a series of two different arrays codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to receive a series of two different arrays with id, name, shortdesc and thumbnail and store them in listing.

This is the original code:

```
if ($cat['parentid'] < 1){

    $data['listing'] = $this->MCats->getSubCategories($id);
```

and then I don't know how to include next this code to receive a series of product with array.id,name,shortdesc,thumbnail:

```
$data['listing'] = $this->MProducts->getProductsByCategory($id);
```

the goal is to get a category page with subcategories first and then with products

Comment: Using two-dimensional arrays, might be your best solution.

Comment: do you have an example? @ShoaibRaza

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can do this:

```
if ($cat['parentid'] < 1){
    $data['listing'] = $this->MCats->getSubCategories($id);
    foreach($data['listing'] as $indx => $val){
       $data['listing'][$indx]['products'] = $this->MProducts->getProductsByCategory($id);
    }
}
```

The expected result of the above code is:

```
'listing' => array(
    'name' => 'sub category name',
    'products' => array(
                     'name' => 'product name'
                  )
)
```

I have not tested it yet, but it would have been better if your have provided an expected result for instance a `print_r` or structure of an array :).

I hope this has given you some idea.